# Expected length of minimum chord

Tags: probability, geometry, expectation, geometric-probability

You are given a circle of radius $1$. Suppose you pick $n$ independent points randomly on the circle and join neighboring points with lines to create chords. What is the expected length of the shortest chord?

I thought about doing this using angles from the center, i.e. minimize $E[\min 2\sin(\theta_i / 2)]$ where $\theta_i$ are random on $[0, 2\pi]$ and sum of $\theta_i = 2\pi$. But not really sure where to go about it from here.

Comment: Are you OK with just a strong hint? I have more than a comment, but I'm nearly spent for the day, so I don't have the energy to work it out all the way.

Comment: Sure, strong hint is ok, but I'd also like to see your solution later if it's particularly elegant :)

Comment: You could look at the distribution of the minimum arc, turn this into a distribution of the minimum chord, and then find the expected value.

Comment: nice question (sorry have no idea on how to solve it)

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find the CDF for the minimum chord length might be something like $$\displaystyle \Pr(C_{\min} \le c) = 1-{\left( 1-\frac{n}{\pi} \sin^{-1}\left( \frac{c}{2} \right) \right) }^{n-1}$$

so the expected minimum chord length might be something like $$\displaystyle \int_{x=0}^{2\sin(\pi/n)}{\left( 1-\frac{n}{\pi} \sin^{-1}\left( \frac{x}{2} \right) \right) }^{n-1}\; dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

I want to point your attention to [The expected minimum length of arc on a circle](https://mathoverflow.net/q/115288)

Then it follows that
$$ \mathbb{E}(C_{\text{min}}) = \frac{1}{\pi}\sin \frac{\pi}{n^2}$$